# Weird array behaviour in C

Tags: arrays, c

so I'm trying to write a simple function that fills a given area of the screen with 'X's. The Area to be filled is user defined.
As (later on) I want to be able to manipulate that display, the 'x's are written into an array. Then, I use this array for my printf().

This works perfectly fine most of the time, but there are two problems:

1. In some cases ( for Example with the values 5,10) one X is missing from the array! (In this case drawPic[8][0] ) It doesn't make any sense to me...

```
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X
 X X X X
X X X X X
```

2. Second, I sometimes get that nice segmentation fault: 11 error. I don't understand why this is the case, it seems quite random. (for example, values 5,12 will give error, values 10,12 will not)

```
/*
Testcase to fill a picture frame
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#define clrscr() printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J")

int main()
{
        int sizeX, sizeY;
        clrscr();
        printf("\n\n\n\n\tEnter picture size (x,y):\t");
        scanf("%d,%d", &sizeX, &sizeY);
        char drawPic[sizeX-1][sizeY-1];
        clrscr();
        for(int i=0; i<sizeY; i++)
        {
                for(int j=0; j<sizeX; j++)
                {
                        drawPic[i][j] = 'X';
                        if(j<sizeX-1)
                                printf("%c ", drawPic[i][j]);
                        else
                                printf("%c\n", drawPic[i][j]);
                }
        }
        // printf("\n\n 9th line 1st char: %c\n\n", drawPic[8][0]);
}
```

/edit:
OKAY, first of all: thanks a lot. Array size was a typical noob mistake, i guess. Correct array size solved issue no.1, and the other problem was that i had i,j of drawPic the wrong way round.

Working code:

```
/*
Testcase to fill a picture frame
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#define clrscr() printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J")

int main()
{
        int sizeX, sizeY;
        clrscr();
        printf("\n\n\n\n\tEnter picture size (x,y):\t");
        scanf("%d,%d", &sizeX, &sizeY);
        char drawPic[sizeX][sizeY];
        clrscr();
        for(int i=0; i<sizeY; i++)
        {       
                for(int j=0; j<sizeX; j++)
                {       
                        drawPic[j][i] = 'X';
                        if(j<sizeX-1) 
                                printf("%c ", drawPic[j][i]);
                        else    
                                printf("%c\n", drawPic[j][i]);
                }
        }
}
```

You're a great community to help out beginners like me with their stupid mistakes which must seem so very obvious to you. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you use `sizeX-1` and `sizeY-1` as array sizes? That means your loops will go out of bounds in the last iteration. Going out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior*. Remember that when declaring an array, the size of an array is the number of elements, not the top index.

Comment: On another (and unrelated) note, the escape code `'\e'` is a compiler-specific, non-standard and therefore also non-portable extension.

Comment: You are probably confused by 0-based indexing. Even though you *define* the array as `char drawPic[sizeX][sizeY];` (without "-1") the maximum allowed index is `drawPic[sizeX-1][sizeY-1]`. This gives you, together with indexes 0, sizeX respectively sizeY array elements! Which you need to declare.

Comment: If that happens everytime you enter these values, you are lucky. That means you can easily run your program in a debugger and step through each instruction while watching the variables' contents. You should get used to use a debugger.

Comment: You are switching index ranges for your array: You define `char drawPic[sizeX-1][sizeY-1];` while you use limits `i<sizeY` and `j<sizeX` together with `drawPic[i][j])` While this is illegal, I doubt that this causes your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is too small:

```
char drawPic[sizeX-1][sizeY-1];
```

This creates a 2D array with dimensions `sizeX-1` and `sizeY-1` which is one less than you requested.  Because array indices in C start from 0, the valid indices for these dimensions are 0 to `sizeX-2` and 0 to `sizeY-2` respectively.

Your loops then use indices up to `sizeX-1` and `sizeY-1` which means you read and write outside the bounds of the array.  This triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which explains the occasional strange results you're seeing.

When declaring an array, the dimensions specify the total number of elements, not the index of the last element.  So you instead should declare it as:

```
char drawPic[sizeX][sizeY];
```

You've also got your loop conditions mixed up:

```
    for(int i=0; i<sizeY; i++)
    {
            for(int j=0; j<sizeX; j++)
            {
```

`i` should have `sizeX` as its limit and `j` should have `sizeY` as its limit, not the other way around.  This can also cause reading outside the array bounds when the two values are not the same.  While it's *probably* not a problem in practice, there's no guarantee it won't be.